# Remove all the elements before the given one from the array

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist

**Hi im trying to solve this question:**
Not all of the elements are important. What you need to do here is to remove from the list all of the elements before the given one.
exemple:

```
remove_all_before([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3) == [3, 4, 5]

remove_all_before([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 2) == [2, 2, 3, 3]

remove_all_before([1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4], 2) == [2, 4, 2, 3, 4]

remove_all_before([1, 1, 5, 6, 7], 2) == [1, 1, 5, 6, 7]

remove_all_before([], 0) == []

remove_all_before([7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], 7) == [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```

For the illustration we have a list [3, 4, 5] and we need to remove all elements that go before 3 - which is 1 and 2.
We have two edge cases here: (1) if a cutting element cannot be found, then the list shoudn't be changed. (2) if the list is empty, then it should remain empty.

```
def remove_all_before(items: list, border: int) -> Iterable:
limit = border
item_list = items

for i in item_list:
    if i < limit:
        return items[i+1:]
    elif limit not in item_list:
        return items
```

this is my code so far...and im stuck.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be solved by using the index method of list and try and except command. here is the solution-

```
def remove_all_before(item, border):
    try:
    #search for the item
        index = item.index(border)
        print(f'the border is found at index {index}')
        return item[index:]
    except ValueError:
        print('border not present')
        return item
```

Answer (score 1):

def remove_all_before(items: list, border: int) -> Iterable:
# your code here

```
for i in range(0, len(items)):
    if (items[i] == border):
        return items[i:]
        
return items
```

Comment: You can improve your answer by providing some explanation and proper formatting. You may also 'demonstrate' your solution with a function call and the returned output.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion this is the best solution, in this one you have the verification if border is in items

```
def remove_all_before(items, border):
    result1 = []
    result2 = []
    for i in range(len(items)):
        if (items[i] == border):
            result1 = items[i:]
            return result1

        result2.append(items[i])

    if (result1 == []):
        return result2
    else:
        return result1
```